# Virtual method of a specialized class

Tags: c++, templates, virtual

Is it possible to define a virtual method on a class which has been specialized? For example

```
template
<class T_DataType>
struct Interface
{
T_DataType data;
...
};

struct NewInterface : Interface<int>
{
virtual
int return_data() = 0;
...
}

struct SubInterface : NewInterface
{
virtual
int return_data();
...
}

int SubInterface::return_data(){ return data;}
```

Comment: Have you tried to do so?

Comment: Yes. Also, there's no "class which has been specialized" here.

Comment: Yes but I tried something similar with the compiler for cuda and it did not work, so I was wondering if this was simply not valid in c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the code is valid and works as intended.

And you don't specialize SubInterface in this case, you inherit it from template specialization.